# While transferring a file to a remote system,i get an error message "The network path was not found". What could be the reasons for that?

Tags: networking, file-transfer

While transferring a file to a remote system,i get an error message "The network path was not found". What could be the reasons for that? os used is windows in both the systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the network connection was lost during transfer.